# Setting the needed index of a Combobox after a method call C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

I'm developing an MVVM application and I have some logic regarding adding the items to the Combobox placed in DataGridTemplateColumn. Each  generated Combobox is binded to a Observablecollection which is refreshed whenever the Datagridrow changes. There are only two items in the Combobox DropDownList. Since the collection is a property of the class needed for each row the ComboBox binding and DropDownList items show up as intened. The one with index [0] is a default value,editable. In index **[1]** I have a SumProduct of some properties of the mentioned class - which works and shows in the DropDownList of the specific ComboBox.

The thing I want to achive is to have this **[1]** item come up on the ComboBox when one of the method to count this SumProducts is called.

**XAML:**

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PRĄD POJEMNOŚCIOWY [A]" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource PRAD_POJEMNOSCIOWY}">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
     <ComboBox Name="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox"
               SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LiniaWyComboBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               IsEditable="True"
               IsReadOnly="False"
               Text="{Binding Prad_pojemnosciowy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
               IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
               PreviewKeyDown="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_OnPreviewKeyDown">
     <ComboBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
       <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
     </ComboBox.Style>

    </ComboBox>
  </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>  
 ....
```

/// one of the properties that triggers the method in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DŁUGOŚĆ [km]" >
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
   <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Name="dlugoscTextBox" 
             Background="{StaticResource navyColor}"   Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
             Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
             TextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged">
           <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="długość" 
                     Mode="TwoWay"
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
              <Binding.ValidationRules>
               <validator:DoubleValidator Min="0" Max="1000"/>
              </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
          </TextBox.Text>
         </TextBox>
       </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_OnPreviewKeyDown:**

```
    private void PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        ComboBox tb = (ComboBox)sender;

        if (tb.Text != null)
        {
            var value = 0.0;
            bool isTry = Double.TryParse(tb.Text, out value);
            if (isTry)
            {

                SelectedItem = value;

                var lineSelected = (modelGPZ.GetLineWyList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.isSelected == true));
                if (lineSelected != null)
                {
                    var u = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
                    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && u != null)
                    {
                        lineSelected.Prad_pojemnosciowy = value;
                        e.Handled = true;
                        u.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
                    }
                }
                refreshLineWy();
                if (tb.Text != lineSelected.LiniaWyComboBox[0].ToString())
                {
                    tb.Text = lineSelected.LiniaWyComboBox[0].ToString();
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                    OnPropertyChanged("LiniaWyComboBox");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Method that is called counts all the neccessary values and shows them in the specific ComboBox - item [1] from DropDownList. Again - what I need is that I want to show the **[1]** item from the ComboBox after updating or from what I think - calling the method that updates the values.

Comment: What confuses me, is that you have this code behind event handling, where you have OnPropertyChanged, which I am used to having in the ViewModel.

Comment: Maybe it is not a right thing to do I guess.. but it works like I want I to :)